# Restangular uses HTTP OPTIONS instead of GET

Tags: django-rest-framework, restangular

I have an Django application that is exposing data using the Django-rest-framework. I can access my objects in json format like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/cemeteries/
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:8000/cemeteries/2/
```

I am now trying to use AngularJS to access the data.I opted for restangular, which seemed simple enough. I have configured restangular as such:

```
demoApp.factory('CbgenRestangular', function(Restangular) {
        return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
            RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8000');
        });
    });
```

And then in my controller:

```
 demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope, simpleFactory, CbgenRestangular, $location){
        $scope.customers = [];

        CbgenRestangular.all("cemeteries/").getList().then(function() {
          console.log("All ok");
        }, function(response) {
          console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
        });
```

The problem is that in my Django logs, I always see an HTTP OPTIONS request:

```
[14/Aug/2013 12:24:12] "OPTIONS /cemeteries/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10245
```

In Firebug it says "Error with status code 0".

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Regards,
Phil

Comment: If you want to use straight up angular instead, I have a seed on git hub that would help you out a ton. Check it out. [Angular/Django Rest](https://github.com/zackargyle/angularjs-django-rest-framework-seed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the reason you're seeing the `OPTIONS` request is due to the browser making a pre-flight CORS request.  If that is the case you probably want to take a look at https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers which is known to play nicely with REST framework.

Comment: You are correct! I was going to answer my own question, but got lost in the fun "trailing slash to my requests" shenanigans. I added `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']` and it worked fine. Thanks!